# C# - Como fazer uma câmera orbital ao redor do player?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou a tentar fazer um jogo storyteller, e quero fazer uma câmera parecida com a do jogo *Life Is Strange*, mas a câmera só roda ao longo do eixo X.

```
    using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class MouseOrbit : MonoBehaviour {

     public float turnSpeed = 4.0f;
     public Transform player;

     public float height = 1f;
     public float distance = 2f;

     private Vector3 offsetX;


     void Start () {

         offsetX = new Vector3(0, height, distance);

     }

     void LateUpdate()
     {
         offsetX = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offsetX;


         transform.position = player.position + offsetX; 
         transform.LookAt(player.position);
     }
 }
```

Já tentei adicionar um offsetY mas continuo sem o resultado pretentido.

Que alterações no código posso fazer para que a câmera comece a rodar ao longo do eixo Y?

Comment: Como você tentou implementar o eixo Y?

Comment: Eu implementei o eixo Y adicionando um novo Vector3 `private Vector3 offsetY;` adicionei também um valor ao offsetY mas com o Eixo Y: `offsetY = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed, Vector3.right) * offsetY;` e somei ao transform.position o valor do offsetY: `transform.position = player.position + offsetX + offsetY;`  Mas à medida que eu vou mexendo o mouse a câmera vai gradualmente se aproximando do ponto, em vez de manter sempre a mesma distância.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de explicar como fiz a Câmera rotar, vou mostrar o script que fiz para o meu player se movimentar. Dependendo de como o player se movimenta as coisas podem enlouquecer os quaternions. Meu script de movimento (extremamente simples) é o seguinte, mas as configurações do `Rigidbody` do player ficaram como a imagem a seguir:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody _rb;
    public float speed = 20f;
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(x * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, z * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Se você não precisar de alguma movimentação específica, sugiro deixar ela restrita.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, o script de rotação da câmera de forma básica ficaria:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float sensitivity = 10f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * 10;
        var rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * 10;

        //Rotate(eixo do player caso ele mude, ângulo de rotação, ambiente)
        transform.Rotate(player.up, -Mathf.Deg2Rad * rotationX, Space.World);
        transform.Rotate(player.right, Mathf.Deg2Rad * rotationY, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Se você utilizar este script, vai perceber que a câmera ao longo do tempo perde seu eixo, mas que é possível recentralizar. Agora, para termos uma boa movimentação de câmera é sempre bom utilizar o `Quaternion.Euler()`:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float sensitivityX = 5f;
    public float sensitivityY = 10f;
    float rotationX = 0f;
    float rotationY = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }
}
```

Lembre-se que a sensibilidade em Y é o movimento de rotação no eixo X, enquanto a sensibilidade no eixo Y é o movimento de rotação no eixo Y. Com uma movimentação simples introduzida:

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float sensitivityX = 5f;
    public float sensitivityY = 10f;
    Vector3 offset;
    float rotationX = 0f;
    float rotationY = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        offset = player.position - transform.position + new Vector3(0, 2, 10f);    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;

        transform.position = player.position + offset;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Está correta a afirmação "sensibilidade em Y é o movimento de rotação no eixo X, enquanto a sensibilidade no eixo Y é o movimento de rotação no eixo Y"  ?

Comment: Quando mexemos no `Mouse Y` estamos mudando nossa perspectiva com uma rotação em X e não em Y. Essa é a ideia dessa frase. https://images.app.goo.gl/mskZkbDFu2qcPGKa7